# ruby get caller full namespace with its parameter name and argument

Tags: ruby

in debugging ruby applications, i am interested in printing in each function the:
- full method namespace
- the method parameters and their arguments (values)

for instance, given the following code block

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def self.baz(p, q)
    end
  end
end
```

when invoking `baz` with arguments, such as `Foo::Bar.baz 'val1', 'val2'`, a message should be printed with the following output `Foo::Bar.baz(p=val1, q=val2)` (or any similar output)

i am familiar with ruby reflection, so i can introduce to each function some additional code to print it. though, single point of modification is a bliss, thus having the each method call another method that will produce such output will be the great.

my questions are:

1. is there anyway to introduce a method, which each other method invoke that will yield an output similar to the above?
2. is there anyway to achieve the same result by binding the printing method (function) to the beginning of any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `#set_trace_func` combined with binding introspection:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def self.baz(p, q)
    end
  end
end

intercept_event = proc do |event, _, _, method_name, method_binding, _|
  if event == 'call'
    self_in_method = method_binding.eval('self')

    parameter_names = self_in_method.method(method_name).parameters.map(&:last)
    parameter_list  = parameter_names.map do |name|
      "#{name}=#{method_binding.local_variable_get(name)}"
    end

    puts "#{self_in_method}.#{method_name}(#{parameter_list.join ', '})"
  end
end

set_trace_func intercept_event

Foo::Bar.baz 'val1', 'val2' # Foo::Bar.baz(p=val1, q=val2)
```

---

**Note** that this will not work for C methods. To handle them, you can check for `'c-call'` instead of `'call'`. You will have to move the method parameters in the string `eval` however, as `self` in those methods is not the same as in Ruby methods.

Comment: @MrRoth, happy to help (: